# How to avoid paginator line items when I write my own pagination templates

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

## Situation

Cake 3.2.4

## What I want

```
<a href="#" class="pagination__item pagination__prev">&larr;</a>
<a href="#" class="pagination__item is-active">1</a>
<a href="#" class="pagination__item">2</a>
<a href="#" class="pagination__item">3</a>
<a href="#" class="pagination__item">4</a>
<a href="#" class="pagination__ellipsis">...</a>
<a href="#" class="pagination__item">10</a>
<a href="#" class="pagination__item pagination__next">&rarr;</a>
```

Pagination links appear like the above with the a href value properly filled out instead of #

## What I tried

```
<?= $this->Paginator->prev('<') ?>
<?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
<?= $this->Paginator->next('>') ?>
```

and then inside AppView.php

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadHelper('Paginator', ['templates' => 'MyPlugin.paginator-templates']);
}
```

and then inside MyPlugin/config/paginator-templates.php

```
<?php

return [
    'number' => '<a href="{{url}}" class="pagination__item">{{text}}</a>',
    'current' => '<a href="{{url}}" class="pagination__item is-active">{{text}}</a>',
    'nextActive' => '<a href="{{url}}" class="pagination__item pagination__prev">{{text}}</a>',
    'prevActive' => '<a href="{{url}}" class="pagination__item pagination__next">{{text}}</a>',
    'ellipsis' => '<a href="{{url}}" class="pagination__ellipsis">{{text}}</a>'
];
```

## What happened

I got the following

```
<div class="pagination">
    <li class="prev disabled"><a href="" onclick="return false;">&lt;</a></li>      
    <li class="active"><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery?page=2">2</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a rel="next" href="/gallery?page=2">&gt;</a></li>    
  </div>
```

How do I get rid of the extra li elements?

I wasn't expecting them. I thought by using my own paginator-templates, I will resolve this issue.

## Updates

When I added the following lines to the template

```
<?php 
debug(get_class($this));

debug($this->Paginator->config('templates'));
?>
```

I get back

```
/src/Template/Products/index.ctp (line 1)
'App\View\AppView'
/src/Template/Products/index.ctp (line 3)
'MyPlugin.paginator-templates'
```

So the debug lines are as expected. What's wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. To me this looks as if none of your templates are actually being applied. Are you sure that your `AppView` class is actually being used?

Comment: How do I check if Appview is being applied? I read http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#the-app-view saw nothing abt this

Comment: You could debug the current class in your view template, like `debug(get_class($this))`. Also check whether the helper has your templates set `debug($this->Paginator->config('templates'))`.

Comment: So I put both debug lines inside the template files?

Comment: I checked. I got back exactly what I expected. So what's next?

Comment: Not really, I just gave it a try using your code and it works as expected: **http://pastebin.com/AaQgHF6D** The one `<li>` is because the disabled templates haven't been overwritten, but apart from that, it looks fine.

Comment: @KimStacks Before displaying the paginator elements can you do a var_dump of the templates like ``<?= var_dump($this->Paginator->templates('number')) ?>`` and add the results to you question?

Comment: Btw your example works is fine for me too, with the same version that you are mentioning. Can't understand what's the problem.

Comment: The error turned out to be something on the css/js side. My code was fine. Sorry abt this.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the example of pagination**

```
<div class="paging" style="  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #60C8F2;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;">
<?php
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'url' => array_merge(array(
        'controller' => $this->params['controller'],
        'action' => $this->params['action'],
    ) , $this->params['pass'], $this->params['named'])
));

echo $this->Paginator->prev('' . '' , array(
    'class' => 'prev',
    'escape' => false
) , null, array(
    'tag' => 'span',
    'escape' => false,
    'class' => 'prev'
)), "\n";
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
    'modulus' => 2,
    'skip' => '',
    'separator' => " \n",
    'before' => null,
    'after' => null,
    'escape' => false
));
echo $this->Paginator->next('' . '', array(
    'class' => 'next',
    'escape' => false
) , null, array(
    'tag' => 'span',
    'escape' => false,
    'class' => 'next'
)), "\n";
?>
</div>
```

**put this code in element pagination.ctp**

**call the component in controller**

```
var $components = array('Paginator');
```

**call the pagination into your controller**

```
 $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 10,
            'order' => array(
            'User.created' => 'desc')

        );
        $results = $this->paginate('User');
```

**And in the ctp file call the pagination**

```
<?php echo $this->element('pagination'); ?>
```